# ¿Por qué no me funciona el evento doubleclick en esta aplicación de Access?

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Access 2003. Necesito que al hacer dobleclick en un elemento seleccionado del listitem, se abra un formulario, pero no me funciona. No escucha ese evento.

El código es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub lswDatos_DblClick()

On Error GoTo lbl_error

Dim sUpdate As String
Dim aSQL() As String

    If Me.lswDatos.ListItems.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    MsgBox ("ha entrado")
    ' Movimientos
    If Me.TABCTL.Value = tCARGAR_MOVIMIENTOS Then
       
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRemoEdit", , , , , acDialog, Me.lswDatos.SelectedItem.Text


End If
```

Se trata de que cada vez que haga doble click en un elemento del listview y no esté vacío, abrir y acceder a un nuevp formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que no escucha el evento doubleclick. ¿Hay alguien sabe como se puede solucionar? Gracias

Comment: Hola. No se activa el evento. El End sub se encuentra más abajo en el código. Gracias por el aporte. Un saludo

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Todo esos aspectos que comentas están bien. De hecho, si le asigno el evento enter, si escucha ese evento. ¿Puede ser que el listview no acepta el doubleclick? Gracias de nuevo

Comment: He editado la respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Hola. Estoy en Vb, no en C#. Ya lo he intentado de la forma de Vb y sigue sin funcionar.  Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Fijate, he creado un proyecto nuevo, he hecho lo que te menciono en mi respuesta y me ha funcionado. De todas formas, he añadido todo el código que uso en mi proyecto en VB.NET para que lo compares y veas si te funciona. Fijate en la útima actualización de mi respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Pero me sigue sin funcionar. De todas formas, supongo que será el listview no admite el dblclick como evento. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo por tu interés

Comment: Que raro, puesto que estoy usando VB.Net y me funciona bien el DoubleClick

Comment: Yo estoy en una aplicación Access 2003. Puede ser que eso tenga algo que ver. Un saludo

Comment: Access es solo un sistema gestor de Base de Datos, no tiene nada que ver con lo que mencionas.

Comment: ¿Has probado a ejecutar tu código paso a paso? Mete un [punto de interrupción](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/how-to/set-and-clear-a-breakpoint) y ejecuta línea a línea para que veas qué está pasando.

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría que pruebes esto y me confirmes si se ejecuta tu evento:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.lswDatos.View = View.Details

        Dim datosPersonas As String() = {"Mendigo", "pepito@mendigo.com"}
        Me.lswDatos.Items.Add("Pepito").SubItems.AddRange(datosPersonas)
    End Sub

    Private Sub lswDatos_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lswDatos.DoubleClick
        MessageBox.Show(lswDatos.SelectedItems(0).Text.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Adjunto una imagen para que veas que funciona como digo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Difícilmente pueda probar eso que está en C#

Comment: Gracias pro notarlo, gracias @Yussef